# Get one Value From multiple Queries SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want to get ONE value from different SELECT queries, I have created the following store procedure, but it keeps giving me an error, I added this into a SQLDATAADAPTER, when i test the query adding the values, it gives me conversion error from nvarchar to int, but I'm not using int in the store procedure.

So I'm doing 4 small selects to get one final value (an item number), every parameter will be bind to a Dropdownlist which will pass the IDs, however I don't know if this is the best approach, or if I should do something different.

```
        @Group as nvarchar(50),
        @Type as nvarchar(50),
        @Brand as nvarchar(50),
        @Art as nvarchar(50),
        @Final as nvarchar(50) OUTPUT
        AS
    begin
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT @group = codigo_group FROM item_group WHERE     (group_art_id = @group)
        SELECT @type = codigo_type FROM item_type WHERE (type_art_id = @type)
        SELECT @brand = codigo_brand FROM item_brand WHERE (brand_id = @brand)
        SELECT @Art = format(COUNT(items.brand_id) +1, '0000')  From items where brand_id=@brand

        Select @Final= @group + '-' + @type + '-' + @brand + @Art
        RETURN @Final

        END
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I think you are missing a declaration.

Comment: Error: There wa an error executing the query. Please check the syntax of the command and if present, the types and values of the parameters and ensure they are correct.

Conversion error, trying to convert nvarchar value ('the desired output') to the type int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you have a stored procedure, because there is no return declaration.

Just remove the final `return`, because the value goes into `@final`.

You can replace it with `return 0` or some other integer.  Stored procedures return a status value that has to be an integer.

If you want to *return* a value, then use `create function` and remove the output parameter.

Comment: Had to actually create a function for this to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to simply comment but I suspect the reason you're getting the error is because of the `RETURN @Final` in your procedure.  The RETURN is a status (which is an INT).

See the following for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378371(v=sql.110).aspx